# Can I install Delta-FL in only part of a basement?

Tags: basement, vapor-barrier, subfloor, underlayment

I've been looking at finishing my basement and am leaning towards using 7/16" OSB over Delta-FL for the subfloor. I was also considering leaving some areas as bare cement (laundry room, utility room, storage) to save some money since I'm not planning to put any real flooring in them.

Will leaving part of the floor uncovered cause any problems seing as Delta-FL is also intended to be a vapor barrier? Obviously the vapor barrier aspect is shot, but is that really a problem? (I also looked at dricore, which seems to take the complete opposite approach by encouraging air circulation.)

If I only do part of the floor, should I still seal the Delta-FL to the walls where possible or just give in to the air circulation approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the Armtec rep had to say:

> We like the idea of Platon venting into an unfinished space so this
>   would be good at your doorway. In regards to the partition walls, yes
>   you would treat that as you would an outside wall.

So I guess not only is it ok, but they consider it a good thing to have some air circulation with unfinished spaces, while keeping the moisture out of the finished rooms.

Comment: [this discussion](http://forums.finehomebuilding.com/breaktime/general-discussion/floating-subfloor-questions) may also be useful